# Update a table field where there are multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update my table (LOCATIONS) to set the field "NO_SHIP" to 'Y' when the following conditions are met. Help please and thank you!

Here is my code so far:

```
UPDATE  LOCATIONS l

SET l.NO_SHIP='Y'

Where ARINVT.ID = FGMULTI.ARINVT_ID And FGMULTI.LOC_ID = L.ID 

And ((FGMULTI.LOT_DATE + ARINVT.SHELF_LIFE) - SysDate) / ARINVT.SHELF_LIFE < .8 

And L.LOC_DESC <> 'NC0101' 

And ARINVT.CLASS = 'FG' 

And L.ID <> 27051
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't join within the `update` itself, never mind introduce references to other tables at will. You need to use a correlated subquery to identify the rows you want to update. Something like:

```
UPDATE  LOCATIONS L
SET L.NO_SHIP = 'Y'
WHERE L.LOC_DESC <> 'NC0101'
AND L.ID <> 27051
AND (
  SELECT MIN(((F.LOT_DATE + A.SHELF_LIFE) - SysDate) / A.SHELF_LIFE)
  FROM FGMULTI F
  JOIN ARINVT A ON A.ID = F.ARINVT_ID
  WHERE F.LOC_ID = L.ID
  AND A.CLASS = 'FG'
) < .8
```

The correlation is that the subquery refers to `L.ID` from the outer update statement.

Completely untested of course, since we don't have your table definitions or sample data. Hopefully that will point you in the right direction though. (Edited to add aggregate function in the subquery so it only returns one row).

Or you could check for existence of any matching row in a subquery:

```
UPDATE LOCATIONS L
SET L.NO_SHIP = 'Y'
WHERE L.LOC_DESC <> 'NC0101'
AND L.ID <> 27051
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT null
  FROM FGMULTI F
  JOIN ARINVT A ON A.ID = F.ARINVT_ID
  WHERE F.LOC_ID = L.ID
  AND A.CLASS = 'FG'
  AND ((F.LOT_DATE + A.SHELF_LIFE) - SysDate) / A.SHELF_LIFE < .8
);
```

You could also have the subquery include its own copy of `locations` with joined to the other two tables, finding the relevant IDs; and then have the update use an `in` clause to update rows matching those IDs. You might want to check the performance of each approach.

Based on your comment that you actually want to update `fgmulti`, and since there isn't an obvious direct link between `arinvt` and `locations` from what you've shown, you could use that method like this:

```
UPDATE FGMULTI
SET NO_SHIP = 'Y'
WHERE LOC_ID IN (
  SELECT F.LOC_ID
  FROM FGMULTI F
  JOIN ARINVT A ON A.ID = F.ARINVT_ID
  JOIN LOCATIONS L ON L.ID = F.LOC_ID
  WHERE L.LOC_DESC <> 'NC0101'
  AND L.ID <> 27051
  AND A.CLASS = 'FG'
  AND ((F.LOT_DATE + A.SHELF_LIFE) - SysDate) / A.SHELF_LIFE < .8
);
```

The subquery can be run on its own to find all rows that need to be updated; the `IN` then applies the update only to those. We still don't have table structures or relationships so I'm just going from the columns you mentioned; which means that all `fgmulti` rows with any `loc_id` found by the subquery will be updated. That may well be much too broad. If `fgmulti` has it's own primary key, use that instead:

```
UPDATE FGMULTI
SET NO_SHIP = 'Y'
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT F.ID
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I ended up running this but now am getting the following: General SQL error.
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Manual SQL Statement -> Finished with 1 error(s). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @MarkStevens - right, I should have included an aggregate function in the subquery so it got a single value. You seem to be looking for *any* value of less than 0.8, so I've used `min()`. I've also added an `exists` version which does the same thing, but stops as soon as it's found a match.

Comment: The second one actually worked great. Unfortunately both FGMULTI and LOCATIONS have a "NO_SHIP" field and I was incorrect in using LOCATIONS. I need to UPDATE FGMULTI.NO_SHIP instead. I have been trying to mod your code with no luck so far. Thank you though, you have been extremely helpful!

Comment: @MarkStevens - added a possible update for that scenario, though the structures and relationships aren't clear still. (Also, I assume you realise that what you're doing won't set values that *don't* match back to N...)

Comment: Thank you! FGMULTI has its own primary key (ID) as well as ARINVT_ID and LOC_ID. LOCATIONS just has primary key (ID) and ARINVT just has primary key (ID). Is there enough here to provide the relationship needed?

Comment: By the way, the code you provided DID work well. I just don't know if it worked too well yet. The NO_SHIP updated exactly as I had hoped but I just need to verify the rest of the data is ok. I am running this on our test system.

Comment: @MarkStevens - the last code snippet, using the F.ID, should work then. The other keys matched what I'd assumed, I think; there's no direct link between L and A, so F is repeated in the subquery to link them. Could also be done with correlation of course. (And... yes, good you're testing it!)